# How to replace character before you parse data

Tags: linux, bash, sed

```
NUM[$a]=`sed '/NE.RE\**/!d;s///;s/\*.*//' < /file.txt
```

When I use this code only the file with `*` as a line separators are only one who where parsed, but when a file has other separator like `-`, probably it will not parse the data that I want to get since `*` was specified. Is it okay if I will going to replace first the `-` character into `*` before I parse the data? How to?

Comment: Do you mean *field separators*?

Comment: Yes, field separators.

Comment: I do see only one back tics in your code. Anyways you should change to parentheses instead the old and outdated back tics. `var=$(code)`

Comment: U should add a sample input and output for getting help.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding a bit better what is going on may help you modify it to fit your needs. The following expressions are not a simple substitution:

```
sed '/NE.RE\**/!d;s///; s/\*.*//' < /file.txt
```

Breaking it down you have two primary parts:

```
sed '/NE.RE\**/!d;s///;
```

Which says:

```
/NE.RE\**/!d;s///;  - match 'NE (anychar) RE (followed by) * (zero or more times)'
                    - if matched, remove first matching 'NE (anychar) RE (any number of *)'
```

Then with what remains of the line:

```
s/\*.*//  - substitute/remove '*' (and any chars that follow)
```

For example if your file.txt contains:

```
this line has NE1RE** and NE1RE* some more
this line is just a line
this line has NE2RE* and some more
this line is just a line
```

Running your sed expression would result in the following assignments in you script:

```
this line has  and NE1RE
this line has  and some more
```

From the explanation, you can see where you can substitute `-` if you need to change its behavior. Good luck.